# Screen needs to be re-rendered to show Real-Time data in React-Native

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, render, mount

I am using componentDidMount to show Firebase real-time data in a React-Native App, but, when I render first time, data is not being showed. I need to go back and navigate again into the page for the data to update and appear on screen. How can I solve this issue and show the data on first try ? Thank you.

```
export default class ForthPage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            reservas: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const readUsersData = () => {
            const nameRef = firebase.database().ref('user0001')
            nameRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
                const state = snapshot.val();
                this.state.reservas = state; //misstake(see my answer)
            });
        }
        readUsersData()
        const pushAdminData = (data) => {
            this.setState({ data })
        }
        pushAdminData(this.state.reservas);
    }

    render() {
        const reservas = JSON.stringify(this.state.reservas);

        return (
            <Background>
                <View>
                    <ScrollView>
                        <Text> Mis reservas: {reservas}</Text>
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </Background>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calling of `readUsersData()` function seems unclear. 
Try defining function in same level as of render,componentDidMount. 
**Like below**

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        reservas: []
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
  const readUsersData = ()=> {
    const nameRef =  firebase.database().ref('user0001')
    nameRef.on('value', (snapshot)=> {
      const state = snapshot.val()
      this.setState({reservas:state}) })
}
readUsersData();
}
```

This will do the job.

Comment: Thank you. Just had to change position of readUsersData function to make it work.

Comment: Please check my own answer below to see how to read real time data in a functional component.

Answer (score 1):

Using `hooks` within a functional component to read real time data from `Firebase` will be something like :

```
    const [reservas, handleReservas] = useState([]);
    const db = () => firebase.database();

    useEffect(() => {
        db();
        console.log('Mounted ');
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        db().ref('/').on('value', handleReservas);
    }, []);
```